# What is this grammar formation called and how is it used ' to + verb + ing '

Tags: gerunds, gerunds-vs-participles

A student gave me this example:

> ...doesn't have an objection in principle to using the Consulting Agreement dated...

She wanted to know how to use this construction (to + verb + ing) and what it is called.

Comment: To" is a preposition here with the gerund-participial clause "using the Consulting Agreement dated... " as its complement. The whole expression "to using the Consulting Agreement dated... " is thus a preposition phrase functioning as complement of "objection".

Comment: Note that the preceding noun really needs mentioning: opposition to accepting this ruling / objection to using this route / ...